# Using a custom JQuery script in WordPress without updating the theme functions.php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I've added a custom JQuery script to a new JS file "themes\twentytwentyone\js\script_new.js".

And I load this new JS file in theme functions.php file.

```
function add_custom_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 
        'my_script', 
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/script_new.js', 
        array( 'jquery' ), 
        '1.0', 
        true
    );
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_script' );
```

This works without any issue. But is there a way to achieve this **without updating the theme functions.php file**?
I'm not sure if updating the functions.php file is good practice.

Comment: Consider using child theme for your case.

Comment: Use plugin called `code snippet` it allow you to write a PHP snippets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using child's theme functions.php is the best practice .

But if you don't want to use functions.php then you can call js file through footer.php or header.php too.

Please note i recommend and it is the safest to make child theme for any customisation and use Child theme's functions.php.